# socket通信でpythonからkotlinへ画像を送ろうとしても不完全な状態になる

Tags: python, python3, kotlin, websocket, socket

タイトルに書いた通りpythonで画像をバイナリで変換しkotlinで受信しようとしてもバイナリデータが途中ですべて0になり不完全な状態で画像が受信されてしまいます。

画像のサイズが349,325バイトに対してkotlinでログを確認したところ2804バイトしか受信していませんでした。
最近プログラミングを始めたもんでコードが冗長ですがご了承ください。

**kotlin側**

```
val socket: Socket?
    val out: BufferedOutputStream?
    try {

        //ソケットの作成
        socket = Socket(IP_ADDR, PORT)
        out = BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())

        val inps = socket.getInputStream()
        val bufferedReader = BufferedInputStream(inps)
        val dis = DataInputStream(inps)

        //パイソンから送られてくる画像のサイズを受信
        val buf = ByteArray(6)
        dis.read(buf)

        val reqData = String(buf, Charset.forName("UTF-8"))

        //画像サイズのバイト配列を作成
        val buffer = ByteArray(reqData)
        var read: Int
        //画像データを受信しbufferへ入れる
        do {
            read = dis.read(buffer)
            if (read  != -1) {
                break
            }

        } while (true)

        out?.close()
        socket?.close()
```

**Python側**

```
import socket
import numpy as np
import time
from PIL import Image
import io
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)#ソケットオブジェクト作成
s.bind(("IPアドレス", ポート番号))    # サーバーのipと使用するポート

print("接続待機中")
while(True):
    s.listen(1)                     # 接続要求を待機
    soc, addr = s.accept()          # 要求が来るまでブロック
    print(str(addr)+"と接続完了")

　　binary = len(f.read())
   filesize = '%s' % binary

   soc.sendall(filesize.encode(encoding='utf-8'))  #クライアントへの返信
   image_pil = Image.open(image_path)
   output = io.BytesIO()
   image_pil.save(output, format='JPEG')
   image_jpg = output.getvalue()
   soc.sendall(image_jpg)
```

Comment: `binary = len(f.read())`, `bb = f.read()` としていますが、1回目の `f.read()` で画像ファイル(`tst.jpg`)の内容を全て読み出してしまっていますので、2回目の `f.read()` では空データが返ってきてしまいます(`bb` は空)。

Comment: bb = f.read()
binary = len(bb)       
bbb = bytearray(bb)
という風に変更をしてみましたがやはり結果は変わりませんでした

Comment: 変数 `bb` や `bbb` は画像データの送信には使用されていないという事でよろしいですか？

Comment: 申し訳ございません実際に使用していたのはimage_pil = Image.open(image_path)
   output = io.BytesIO()
   image_pil.save(output, format='JPEG')
   image_jpg = output.getvalue()の部分でした。
確認不足でした。

Comment: Python 側で画像データを送信する部分(`image_pil = Image.open(image_path)`以降)については PIL を使わなくてもよいかと思います。`with open(image_path, 'rb') as f:`, `b = bytearray(f.read())`, `soc.sendall(b)`, `soc.close()` 受信する kotlin 側については分からないのですが、`nc` コマンドを使ってデータ全てを読み出す事ができました。

Comment: 試してみましたがやはり完全に復元できていないのでおそらくKotlin側で問題があると思いました。
ありがとうございました

Comment: kotlin側のコードを眺めていて気が付いたのですが、`val buffer = ByteArray(reqData)` となっている部分で、`reqData` が String 型になっています。ここは ByteArray のサイズを指定するので、`reqData` は整数値(整数型)である必要があるのではないでしょうか。